# Retrieving data from Azure

Tags: java, android, azure, android-activity

I created an azure account connected it with a current android application, created a table and added data to this table from within my application. The text is added into a textbox and one the button is clicked the data is sent to Azure. I want to be able to retrieve this data in the "Text" field in a list. Could anyone show me how I would do this.

My Code is as fallows

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MobileServiceClient mClient;
    private EditText title;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "https://craigsapp.azure-mobile.net/",
                    "BTkcgnFQvevAdmmRteHCmhHPzdGydq84",
                    this
            );
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void onClickB(View view) {

title= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        Item item = new Item();
        item.Text = title.getText().toString();

        mClient.getTable(Item.class).insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<Item>() {
            public void onCompleted(Item entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                if (exception == null) {
                    // Insert succeeded
                } else {
                    // Insert failed
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Item Activity

```
public class Item {
    public String Id;
    public String Text;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the POJO Class file `Item.java`.

```
public class Item {
    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("text")
    private String text;

    public Item() {}
    public Item(String id, String text) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text
    }

    // The getter and setter functions for echo property, and the functions `toString` and `equals`
    ......
}
```

As reference, there is a similiar sample project `GetStartedWithData`, please see https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/GettingStartedWithData/Android/GetStartedWithData/src/com/example/GetStartedWithData.

For inserting data into mobile service, please refer to the section [`How to: Insert data into a mobile service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#inserting).

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve your data from azure sql database you have to do it through an asynctask or android service and then use a broadcast receiver to get it to a text field.
If you still need help comment below.